# Replacing Nodes in the nth position Link List

Tags: c++, c++11

so i want to Write code to implement the replaceNode(…) function that takes pointers to OldNode and
NewNode as inputs using the function header given below. Also include code for the special
cases where OldNode is the head or tail nodes of the list. Assume the list is never empty
before this function is called and that all nodes have been created dynamically

```
void List::replaceNode(Node *OldNode, Node *NewNode)
{
//write code here
}
```

[image: Picture TO illustrate what i want to do]

i have no idea how to go about doing this can some one please help me with this

Comment: Why is this marked down

Comment: Read the tooltip at the DV button.

Comment: @jake123 I think the reason is that you provided no evidence of researching before asking the question.

Comment: This code is easier to write if you first draw the result in the diagram you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASE 1: where OldNode is **neither** **HEAD** or **TAIL** (Singly LinkedList)

You need to know about the node pointing the OldNode, lets call it *PrevPntr & the node which oldNode is pointing to. 
Then it will be something like:

```
          `PrevPntr->next = NewNode;
           NewNode->next  = OldNode->next
```

else
just replace the **DATA** of OldNode by data of NewNode (*some constraints will be there in this case*).

CASE 2: where OldNode is HEAD (Singly LinkedList).

Then it will be something like:

```
          `
           NewNode->next  = OldNode->next
```

CASE 3: where OldNode is TAIL (Singly LinkedList).

You need to know about the node pointing the OldNode, lets call it *PrevPntr.
Then it will be something like:

```
          `PrevPntr->next = NewNode;
```

Comment: @jake123 Now that you added the picture it's even trivial to see how you should do that.

Comment: @Jake123 Watch a video lecture or refer some text to clarify the logic of LL.

Comment: can it be done like this
`oldNode = newNode;
delete (OldNode );`

Comment: @jake123 OldNode is a pointer pointing to node containing 125 as data, so if you do oldNode = newNode; delete (OldNode );  then oldPointer will simply start pointing to NewNode instead of pointing to node of 125 which is certainly not the thing you want. Watch lecture by PP chakravarty on youtube for better clarity on linkedlist.